# Stored keyword in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Delphi allows a stored keyword when defining properties as follows:

```
property Fields: TIndexDefs read FFields write SetFields stored FieldsStored;
```

What is the purpose of the keyword and what does it do?

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using, that it's not described in the documentation?

Comment: @RobKennedy, Have you ever tried using the documentation of any Delphi version after Delphi 7? (.. and yes that question is rhetorical)

Comment: @SlashV, the wording from the Delphi 7 help file is identical to [the wording in the documentation today](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Properties). The "bash Delphi's documentation" game has gotten old. If you have nothing constructive to offer on the topic, please keep your rhetorical questions to yourself. Speaking of old, my question you're replying to from three and a half *years* ago was not rhetorical.

Comment: @RobKennedy, surprisingly I thought your comment was the one being particularly "unconstructive", but I admit I took the "bash the delphi docs" bait. However regarding those: The latest version I have is 2010 and the help system is just so awful it isn't funny. Hence, I appreciate answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: @RobKennedy I am using XE7. If it's in the documentation, I can't find it.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Properties#Storage_Specifiers

Comment: @RobKennedy They don't make it easy to find. That result shows with Google, but not the search engine I habitually use. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Also, it's result No. 11 when searching the documentation for "property stored." It jumps to No. 6 when I add "read" and "write" to the query. In this case, though, I found the page by directly navigating the XE7 documentation: Delphi Language Guide, Classes and Objects, Properties, Storage Specifiers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From my Delphi 7 help file:

> The optional stored, default, and
> nodefault directives are called
> storage specifiers. They have no
> effect on program behavior, but
> control whether or not to save the
> values of published properties in form
> files.
>
> The stored directive must be followed
> by True, False, the name of a Boolean
> field, or the name of a parameterless
> method that returns a Boolean value.
> For example,

```
property Name: TComponentName read FName write SetName stored False;
```

> If a property has no stored directive,
> it is treated as if stored True were
> specified.

It controls whether or not to store a property relating to a component in the .DFM file for the form.

Comment: Your guess is right. :-) However it works for **all** components, not only visual controls.

Comment: Change "visual control" to "component", and I'll upvote this answer. :-)

Comment: "Sounds like"? Cmw, that's *exactly* what the documentation says in the first paragraph you quoted. No need to guess.

Comment: @Ken: changed =]
@Rob: Yes that's exactly what it _says_ but I didn't test what it actually _does_.

Comment: @KenWhite, @Uli - the Stored keyword can by applied to ANY component but only makes sense if the property to which it applies is "published". See my answer. And since it makes sense to have `published` properties only for visual components, results that...

Comment: @Rigel: While you can put it on any property, it is useless unless the property is published and it's a component; otherwise, it has zero effect, which makes the information worthless. You **can** wave your hand in the air like a magic wand and wish that every day was Friday, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ServerOverflow It have sense also for non visual components to have published properties which is used mostly. E.g. TDataSource

Comment: @Livius - I don't understand you,.

Comment: @ServerOverflow You have write that "And since it makes sense to have published properties only for visual components" it is not true that only visual component have sense to have published properties, look at e.g. TDataSoures

Answer (score 8):

This keyword determines if a property value should be saved in a form file; it is `true` by default. It can be useful to avoid, for example, saving big chunks of binary information in your `.dfm` file (for example, an image component that must read its contents at runtime only.)

Comment: upvote for providing an actual example where Stored can be useful!

Answer (score 1):

The stored directive takes a Boolean value: a method that returns a Boolean result, a Boolean-type field reference, or a constant expression of Boolean type. The property’s RTTI records the field offset, method reference, or constant value, and Delphi’s IDE uses this information to decide whether to omit the property from the .dfm file.

The IDE calls the method, checks the field’s value, or uses the constant Boolean value, and if the value is False, the property is not saved to the .dfm file. If the stored value is True, the default behavior occurs, namely, that the property is stored if its value is different from the default value.

Tips and Tricks

- The stored directive is often misunderstood. Setting stored to True does not force Delphi to store the property value in the .dfm file. True is the default value of the stored directive. Instead, all you can do is omit the property from the .dfm file by setting stored to False.
- You can use stored with properties at any access level, *but it has meaning only for published properties*.
- If you use a method name, the method can be static or virtual, but not dynamic or a message handler.
- A field reference can be a field name, a record member, or an array element with a constant index. The field reference must have a Boolean type.

Reference: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/delphi-in-a/1565926595/re307.html